# Does BytesInUse in Tensorflow get all the GPU memory used on one gpu divice or only the GPU memory used by the model where BytesInUse is?

Tags: tensorflow

If there are several Tensorflow models running on gpu0, and I 
run 'tf.contrib.memory_stats.BytesInUse()' in model1, will the result be the gpu memory used by all the models, or only the memory used by model1?

And if I already have a Tensorflow model running on GPU, how can I get the amount of gpu memory used by the model by using BytesInUse in another python script?